# Exit if ANY variable expands to an empty string?

Tags: bash, shell

If I want to have my bash script exit whenever an unset variable is expanded, I can use `set -u`.

Is there an equivalent which cause the script to exit if **any** variable expands to an empty string? I have hundreds of variables so I do not want to test them individually with `-z`.

Comment: This really sounds like an XY problem. Why do you want to abort if a variable holds an empty string? Is it really a "life or death" condition?

Comment: "Hundreds of variables" sounds like a script in dire need of better data structures than `bash` can provide.

Comment: Might be a good idea to share a snippet of your scripts. As per other comments - there might be a better solution for your specific case than to manually update all references.

Comment: Not having assigned a value to a given variable before trying to expand it is an entirely different thing, much more plausibly erroneous, than is expanding a variable that was affirmatively assigned an empty value.

Comment: I am loading in data from a CSV which are converted to variables and then expanded into a bash string template.  A single, simple option similar to `set -u` would be helpful.  I could obviously check vars upon creation, but I was interested in something more elegant.

Answer (score 3):

There's no global feature to allow exiting on null values.

But you can use this *parameter expansion*:

```
echo "${var:?}"
```

that yields:

```
bash: var: parameter null or not set
```

---

*Parameter Expansion* expands parameters: `$foo`, `$1`. You can use it to perform string or array operations: `"${file%.mp3}"`, `"${0##*/}"`, `"${files[@]: -4}"`. They should **always** be quoted.

See: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073 and
`LESS='+/Parameter Expansion' man bash`
Also see [wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe](https://web.archive.org/web/20230108022244/http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe)

Comment: I was looking for an answer like `set -u` which would apply globally for **all variables** expanded within the script.

Comment: @JonathanCross Bash doesn't have that feature.

Comment: That sounds like the correct answer, even if it is disappointing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this idea below will work for this use case - worth sharing.

The `set` command can be used to iterate over all known variable. OP states that all variables should be checked - so one possibility will be to iterate over all (relevant) variable at a point when they should be set, and then unset them (or abort) at that point.

Example below assumes all input variables start with v_

```
# Read CSV/data

# Check all variables that have data
# Abort if empty variable exits
set | egrep '^(v_)[^=]*=$' | {
    if read x ; then
        echo "Variable ${x%=} not set"
        exit 1
# Option 2: unset the variable, will fail when it will be referenced
        eval unset ${x%=}
    fi
}

# Option 2: unset the variable, will fail when it will be referenced
set | egrep '^(v_)[^=]*=$' | {
    if read x ; then
        eval unset ${x%=}
    fi
}
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but a decent hack to achieve the same thing!